# How many combinations of 4 numbers are there $(A, B, C, D)$ under conditions that $A \lt C$ and $B \le D$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$A, B ​​, C , D$ are elements of $\{1,2 , \dots, 100\}$. How many combinations of $4$ numbers are there $(A, B, C, D)$ under conditions that $A \lt C$ and $B \le D$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Choosing the couple $(A,C)$ is equivalent of choosing two distinct numbers in the set. There are $\binom{100}{2}=4950$ ways.

2) Choosing the couple $(B,D)$ is equivalent of choosing two distinct numbers in the set or two equal numbers in the set.  There are $\binom{100}{2}+100=5050$ ways.

3) $(A,C)$ and $(B,D)$ can be chosen independently so the final number of combinations is  $4950\cdot 5050=24997500$.